# String with same amount of characters takes different space in matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a strange problem with a formatted string in Matplotlib. I want the string part in the tuple to be aligned left in legend and the numbers aligned right, as well as all labels of the legend aligned respectively.

Therefore, I defined a maximum length = 17 for the string and tried to format it with the following code. As you can see the actual length of the label string seems to be 17, however somehow the strings take different amount of space in the legend. What is the reason for this and how can I achieve alignment of the labels?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l=[('string1', 1), ('string200', 10.5), ('str3', 12.5)]

x=[1,2,3]
y=[1,2,3]

for tup in l:
    s_label='{0:<10s}{1:>7s}'.format(tup[0],str(tup[1]))
    print(len(s_label))
    ax.plot(x, np.add(y,tup[1]), label=s_label)

ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a font with all characters having the same length, you could set a monospace font. This looks like the font of an old typewriter.

In general, proportional fonts are much easier to read. The character widths are proportional: "i" takes up less space than an "m" or a "W".

```py
ax.legend(prop={'family': 'monospace'}
```

An alternative to what you want to accomplish could be to create 3 legend entries more, and use 2 columns for the legend. A legend consists of a combination of a handle (the colored line) and a label. To accompany the extra labels, you can create dummy handles.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l = [('string1', 1), ('string200', 10.5), ('str3', 12.5)]
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
for tup in l:
    ax.plot(x, np.add(y, tup[1]), label=tup[0])

empty_handle = patches.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='none', visible=False)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
handles += [empty_handle for tup in l]
labels += [lval for lstr, lval in l]
ax.legend(handles, labels, ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

The plot shows the two variations for the legend:

[image: plot with legends]